# How to duplicate a Azure SQL DB table alongwith the data from SSMS?

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

I have a Azure SQL DB table of around 3GB data. I want to make copies of the table to perform a testing on large data. So how can I create copies of this table to have 9GB, 12GB, etc. data.
e.g. Table1 copy to Table1_copy1, Table1_copy2,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in SSMS open a new query window and then do something like

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
```

Change NewTable to the name that the new table(copy) should have, change OldTable to the name of the current table

This will copy over the basic table structure and all the data...It will NOT do any of the constraints, you need to script those out and change the names in those scripts

But if the table with large data, it will take much time to copy the table. I would suggest you use some other ways, such as:

1. Export the table to an csv file and and import it with SSMS **SQL Server import and export wizard**.
2. Using ETL tools, Such as [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). It have good performance
   to copy the big data and support auto create the table in sink side.
   [image]

Ref this tutorial: [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

HTH.

Comment: This is perfect. It worked fine for me. 3GB table copy it took on an average 1.5mins in SSMS. I copied it 3 times and it took 1.22, 2.11, 1.41mins.